# MYSQL Update table not working with Java implementation

Tags: java, mysql, database

In my Java program i'm using a Mysql database. Before implementing every query in Java i'm testing it using SQLDeveloper to be sure it works.

In SQLDeveloper the following query works perfectly:

```
UPDATE keyword t JOIN banned b ON t.excerpt LIKE CONCAT_WS('', '%', b.word, '%')
SET t.filter = 'BANNED'
WHERE t.filter IS NULL
```

(It just mark as banned, in a list of titles, a title that contains a banned word (i.e. profanity).

Now when i implement this query in Java, the code runs perfectly (no errors, no Exceptions) but actually the DB is not updated as it is using SQLDeveloper. Here is the code:

```
    String query = "UPDATE keyword t JOIN banned b ON t.excerpt LIKE CONCAT_WS('', '%', b.word, '%') SET t.filter = 'BANNED' WHERE t.filter IS NULL;";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    preparedStatement.close();
```

I created other queries similar to this one and they work. Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn`t work?Maybe all fields are already updated

Comment: 100% sure, i use SELECT queries on the DB to check if it is updated or not

Comment: @MarcoMicheli It is not necessary to use the `;` at the end of your query. check for your server logs . there must be an exception if it failed

Answer (score 0):

you need commit you SQL statements using [Connection.commit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

```
String query = "UPDATE keyword t JOIN banned b ON t.excerpt LIKE CONCAT_WS('', '%', b.word, '%') SET t.filter = 'BANNED' WHERE t.filter IS NULL;";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
connect.commit();
preparedStatement.close();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i'm getting: java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true

Comment: Before `connect.commit()` add `connect.setAutoCommit(false)`;

Comment: Tried also this one but still not updating

Comment: @MarcoMicheli By default autocommit is true so you are getting that exception.try to print System.out.println(preparedStatement.executeUpdate()),if you get 0 then then it update and if you get 1 then its updated

Comment: I get 0, but how can it be possible that 0 rows are updated if with the same query on SQLDeveloper 26 rows are updated?

Comment: version of mysql connector/j?

Comment: Mysql: 5.1.32, Java: 1.6.0_34